# What exactly is timekey_wait parameter in Fluentd?

Tags: kibana, fluentd

I'm new in EFK. I have a problem with showing logs in Kibana. I already resolved, but I'm not sure of my approach.

Problem: Kibana shows log after 10 minutes when Elasticsearch is restarted.

I studied in https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section

And I found out that if I configure timekey_wait parameter in buffer section is 0s, Kibana shows logs without delay.
The problem is resolved, but I have still concerned about timekey_wait parameter.

1. Are there others impacted by the change?
2. Why is timekey_wait needed? Please give me an example of the necessity of it.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2 ) According to the documentation by using **timekey_wait** parameter fluentd waits the specified amount of time, before writing chunks. By this way delayed log lines that needs to be in the same log chunk won't be missed.
If your **timekey** is 60m and **timekey_wait** is 10m, now the chunks will be written after 70m not 60m.

If you don't have delayed log lines to be come it becomes less important.In one of my implementations, I use **flush_interval** parameter. That way **timekey** is not needed. (buffer chunks will be flushed after this time)

Comment: Link to documentation: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/webhdfs#timekey_wait